# Update cell values where data is missing using function row-by-row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Suppose I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([['name1', 2, 3, 'red'], ['name2', 4, 5, 'orange'], ['name3', 6, 7, '-'], ['name4', 8, 9, '-']], \
              columns=('names', 'data1', 'data2', 'category'))
        df

Out[1]:
     name   data1   data2   category
0   name1       2       3        red
1   name2       4       5     orange
2   name3       6       7          -
3   name4       8       9          -
```

For some rows, data is missing in certain columns, denoted with '-':

What I want to do is fill in the missing data row-by-row.  There is a function that can identify the correct category for each row if it has the name passed into it.  I've used arbitrary terms to keep the question general and broad since the actual function pulls data from a database.  For example:

```
In [2]: import library as lib
        lib.get_category('name1')

Out[2]: ['red']
```

How would I go about updating all missing values using the function row-by-row?  I've tried using df.loc to get all rows with missing data and passing in a series of the corresponding names into the function, but it only updates any missing values with the last value in the series.  I believe the core issue here is with iterating correctly.

The final expected output should look something like this (assuming that lib.get_category('name3') returns ['yellow'] and lib.get_category('name4') returns ['green']:

```
Out[1]:
     name   data1   data2   category
0   name1       2       3        red
1   name2       4       5      orange
2   name3       6       7      yellow
3   name4       8       9       green
```

Comment: what is the final expected output? and is there a dict which you are referencing(post the same as well) Thanks

Comment: @anky_91 I added the expected output.  Here is a dict for the DataFrame:  

           data = {'name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'], 'data1': [2, 4, 6, 8], 'data2': [3, 5, 7, 9], 'category': ['red', 'orange', '-', '-']}  
Is this what you were requesting?

Comment: exactly, i can help, but you need to have  a mapping dictionary for this. does `apply()` work? by mapping dict i mean something like `{'name1': 'red', 'name2': 'orange', 'name3': 'yellow', 'name4': 'green'}`

Comment: `apply()` is very close to what I want.  I was able to get a unique output for every row by using Mohit's method and modifying it slightly to use try/except in the case that the function didn't return anything.  Ideally I would like it to skip over everything with data already in it so that I don't accidentally modify data already present (and for better performance).  So in my example, the first two rows would be skipped and the function would run on the last two.

Comment: not sure until i see the library but `df.category.replace('-',np.nan).fillna(df['name'].apply(func))` might work

Comment: This does seem to work as long as I set `df['category'] = df.category.replace('-',np.nan).fillna(df['name'].apply(func))`.  An interesting work-around that I wouldn't have thought of, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for that:

```
import library as lib
def func(name):
    return lib.get_category('name1')

df['category'] = df['name'].apply(func)
```

The apply function `func` will take values from name column and return a value for the corresponding row. So edit your function accordingly.

Also note that the above code will replace the existing category value of the column. But as you mentioned that the category can be derived from the name, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df.category.astype('str')=='-','category']=df[df.category.astype('str')=='-']['names'].apply(lib.get_category)
```

Just use apply function with loc to find the rows where it need to apply.

Comment: This seems like what I need here.  Is there a way to pass in more parameters into the get_category function using this method? I'm getting errors, likely because I'm not giving the function everything it needs.  Suppose that the `get_category` function needed a second parameter of 'name' (indicating the type of data passed in) in addition to the string of the name for that row, would this method still work? Eg `lib.get_category('name1', 'name')`

Comment: @AlexW if you need more parameters then just pass it with column names.